# How to get conditional css to work on Blogger/Blogspot?

Tags: css, conditional-statements, blogger, blogspot

I'm trying to get conditional CSS to work in Blogger / Blogspot - might be missing something obvious and fundamental to make it work but here we go.

A number of tutorials I've found have provided instructions but when i follow them they don't work (nb: they work perfectly when used in the template body to hide certain widgets on certain pages but i can't get them to work to style different elements differently on different pages).

So, as an example I want to have a different date background color depending on what page you're on [here](http://mgmmediaadditionaldemoblog.blogspot.com.au/).

The date header styling is:

```
    .date-header span {
      background-color: #FF8BBF;
      color: $(date.header.color);
      padding: $(date.header.padding);
      letter-spacing: $(date.header.letterspacing);
      margin: $(date.header.margin);
    }
```

I want the background color of the date to be different on another page, so as per various tutorials I've added the following code just above the template closing head tag.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "http://mgmmediaadditionaldemoblog.blogspot.com.au/search/label/Test2"'>
<style>
  .date-header span {
    background-color: #FF937E;
  }
</style>
</b:if>
```

But it's not changing the colour on the page specified. I've tried variations - putting the conditional code in the b:skin or b:template-skin sections of the head but i can't make it work - any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to check conditions from JS and apply styles dynamically there.

Comment: use jquery, check url and then apply color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:
    `<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == &quot;Test2&quot;'>
    <style>
     .date-header span {
    background-color: #FF937E!important;
  }
</style>
</b:if>`

`Test2` is the label, and add `!important` to your color code to make browser load `background-color: #FF937E` instead of `background-color: #FF8BBF;`.

I wait for your feedback :)

Comment: You are a legend, this has worked perfectly and I can adapt to fix other similar issues (e.g. background color, h1 underline color etc) - thank you so much!